# React Router Dom Calling an Action

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-dom

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/signout" component={ SignOut } />
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={RequireAuth(Dashboard)} />
    <Route path="/" component={IsAuthenticated(App)} />
    <Route component={NoMatch}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

In the code above every time a user navigates to signout it calls an action that logs the user out then redirects them to the home page. It does nothing except invoke the function. Is there a way I can call the action creator without actually rendering a component?

```
class SignOut extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.signoutUser();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <h1></h1>
    )
  }
}
```

Having the code above just seems so wasteful. And I can't render nothing otherwise it throws an error. Any way around this?

Comment: Looks like the `render` prop might be something you can use: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func

Comment: Usually this kind of action is directly handled by a backend server, handle it in front has no interest.